# what does find_interface: error in godot vr mean?

Tags: virtual-reality, godot

I was following this tutorial https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/tutorials/vr/vr_starter_tutorial.html
for vr in godot and the first few lines of code are (in func _ready())

```
var VR = ARVRServer.find_interface("OpenVR") ###
if VR and VR.initialize():
    get_viewport().arvr = true
    get_viewport().hdr = false
    OS.vsync_enabled = false
    Engine.target_fps = 90
```

when I run the code I get the error find_interface: Condition "idx == -1" is true. Returned: _null
The program runs, but the camera is static and moving the headset doesn't do anything. Doing vr stuff atm is probably out of my league but I just wanted to play around with it. please let me know if you have a solution, thanks! (also i am using a samsung odyssey plus)

Comment: This error most likely means the OpenVR interface couldn't be initialized successfully because it can't be found. (To check this, try replacing the "OpenVR" string with anything else.)

Also, maybe you're missing the GDNative plugin that implements the VR interface in question.

Comment: Thank you for responding, the plugin in question is only the godot-openvr download from the asset library correct? I have that downloaded and I also tried using other strings, the only valid string that was possible though was Native Mobile which just makes a fish lens effect on the screen.

Comment: This error means that Godot was unable to find your headset. DId you manage to make it work?

I just had to add the *godot-openvr* add-on to make the VR Starter Tutorial works with my Valve Index